# jQuery sliding containers to left and right with arrows

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a webpage and I used this tutorial: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/

Now I want to control scrolling through the pages using 'previous' and 'next' buttons. I can't seem to find how that should work.

The code to get the sliding containers working is this:

```
$('a.link').click(function () {  
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '400px', '800px', '1200px', '1600px', '2000px')
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '800px', '1600px', '2400px', '2800px', '3200px')
        $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;  
    }); 
});

function setPosition(check, div, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6) {
if(check==='#box1')
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p1, 800);
    }
else if(check==='#box2')
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p2, 800);
    }
else if(check==='#box3')
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p3, 800);
    }
else if(check==='#box4')
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p4, 800);
    }
else if(check==='#box5')
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p5, 800);
    }
else 
    {
        $(div).scrollTo(p6, 800);
    }
};
```

I created a previous and next button like this

```
    <input type="button" class="next">
    <input type="button" class="prev">
```

And I tried to implement this option but it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/s2TJQ/4/

I think this should be simple, but I just can't get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me, what's the problem again?

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com I tried implementing the jsfiddle, but it didn't work for me. So, I should be able to go '800px' to the left and '800px' to the right using arrows, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: For a start it seems your left and right buttons are input field but your JS is checking for a click event on an anchor with a class of "link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now what you trying to achieve. Well, actually the source you want to use isn't very good code, makes things harder to solve.

First, give the First link the 'selected' class by default:

```
<li><a href="#box1" class="selected link">Home</a></li>
```

Here is the original handler for click (just for reference/your understanding):

```
$('a.link').click(function () {  
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
    setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '400px', '800px', '1200px')
    setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '800px', '1600px', '2400px')
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;  
});
```

Now, what you want to do is extract the body of it to a method, it would look like this:

```
function performScroll(boxHref) {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(boxHref).attr('href'), 800);
    setPosition($(boxHref).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '400px', '800px', '1200px')
    setPosition($(boxHref).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '800px', '1600px', '2400px')
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
    $(boxHref).addClass('selected');
}

$('a.link').click(function () {  
    performScroll(this);
    return false;  
});
```

Now, that you got the click method extracted, we'll make use of it, in our Next/prev handlers:

```
$('.next').click(function () {  
    // find current selected item
    var nextBox = $("a", $("li > a.selected").parent().next());
    performScroll(nextBox);
    return false;  
});
```

Is this working for you? If yes, now the challenge for you: Implement the "prev" button yourself! :)

**EDIT**

Corrected .next handler

Comment: Can you ensure that you are using a current JQuery version (for example 1.9.1) instead of the old 1.3.2 version in the original code?

Comment: OOOMG! YOU ARE MY HERO. Okay, sorry, but thank you so much, it works!!! I'll accept the challenge and try to get the 'prev' button myself, thanks!

Comment: Got it: $('.prev').click(function () {  
     // find current selected item
     var prevBox = $("a", $("li > a.selected").parent().prev());
     performScroll(prevBox);
     return false;  
 });